# My Chrysler 300

Tags: fuel-system, drivetrain

someone put sugar in my tank I had it dropped and clean but when they put it back together when you drive at 35-40 mph, it vibrates underneath the car what do you think it is?

Comment: I would check to see if the exhaust system was rehung improperly. It may have been moved out of the way during the tank work.

Answer (score 1):

First thing I would check is the tank loose?

If so tighten the mounting bolts.

Depending on the design it should be pretty easy to jack up the car and check how loose the tank is.

Answer (score 0):

Is that all they did? Sugar in your tank? Are you sure they did nothing else?

That's a rear-wheel drive car, right? I think you may have lost a driveshaft balance weight. Coincidental. Unless... the vandal also loosened your lug nuts or u-joint nuts, either of which could make a car vibrate unpredictably at speed.

Answer (score 0):

Return your vehicle to the garage that carried out the work in case they need to do any rectification work, or, advise you of anything else that may be developing